# Bootstrap dropdowns clipped by container with overflow:auto

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, overflow

I have a vertical fixed sidebar at the right side of my app. It contains a list of user avatars, each of them showing a card with a list of options at their left side when clicked, which displays some information and actions related to that user. This is done by using a [`dropdown-menu`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns) with `position: absolute;` for each avatar in the list.

Initially, that sidebar only had a few elements, so I didn't even think about overflows. However, now I need it to be able to contain as many elements as the user wants, so I need the inner list to scroll if the content overflows the sidebar.

I tried setting `overflow-y: auto;` on the sidebar or the inner list, but in both cases, that results in the dropdowns being clipped by the container with `overflow: auto;`.

Here's the most relevant code. And below I also attached a code snippet with a full example showing the said behavior (run it fullpage, for some reason the dropdowns are not triggering in the embed mode).

```html
<aside class="fav-bar">
  <h4 class=sr-only>Favorites</h4>
  <ul class="fav-list">

    <li class="fav dropdown">
      <a class="fav-thumb dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
         <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/70/70" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="fav-card dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        Some content here
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="fav dropdown">...</li>
    <li class="fav dropdown">...</li>
    ...

  </ul>
</aside>
```

```css
.fav-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
}

.fav-bar .fav-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto; /*** This is what I need ***/
}

.fav-bar .fav-list .fav .fav-card {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 65px; /* This would normally be 71px */
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```css
.fav-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  border-left: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

.fav-bar .fav-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto; /*** This is what I need ***/
}

.fav-bar .fav-list .fav {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.fav-bar .fav-list .fav img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.fav-bar .fav-list .fav .fav-card {
  width: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 65px; /* This would normally be 71px */
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<aside class="fav-bar">
  <h4 class=sr-only>Favorites</h4>
  <ul class="fav-list">
  
    <li class="fav dropdown">
      <a class="fav-thumb dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
         <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/70/70" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="fav-card dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        Some content here
      </div>
    </li>
  
    <li class="fav dropdown">
      <a class="fav-thumb dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/70/70" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="fav-card dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        Some content here
      </div>
    </li>
  
    <li class="fav dropdown">
      <a class="fav-thumb dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/70/70" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="fav-card dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        Some content here
      </div>
    </li>
  
    <li class="fav dropdown">
      <a class="fav-thumb dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/70/70" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="fav-card dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        Some content here
      </div>
    </li>
  
    <li class="fav dropdown">
      <a class="fav-thumb dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/70/70" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="fav-card dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        Some content here
      </div>
    </li>
  
    <li class="fav dropdown">
      <a class="fav-thumb dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/70/70" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="fav-card dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        Some content here
      </div>
    </li>
  
  </ul>
</aside>
```

As you can see in the CSS comments, what I tried is setting the `.fav-list` to `overflow: auto;` (I also tried doing it on the `.fav-bar` instead), but this makes the dropdown to clip to the borders of the container. Also, I modified the positioning of the dropdowns so a part of them can be seen when triggered.

So my question is, **is there any way to achieve the behavior I need?**

I've been googling for hours, but I couldn't find anything that worked. Until now, the "best" solution I found (which I didn't try yet) is to use Bootstrap popovers with `data-container="body"` instead of dropdowns, but I would really prefer to modify my markup as less as possible, since those cards are pretty complex and that would imply some big changes in both CSS and JS.

And that's it. Do you know any solution I can try to make the list scroll while keeping the dropdowns visible?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve what you're trying to do with CSS alone. If you set the `overflow-y` of `<ul class="fav-list">` to `scroll` and it's `overflow-x` to `visible` then you will notice that the `dropdown` menu gets clipped although you can scroll up and down to view all the `<li>`'s. Only way using which the `dropdown` menu doesn't get clipped is setting the`overflow` of `<ul class="fav-list">` to `visible` but then you can't scroll up and down to view all the `<li>`'s.

You've two options, either you can restructure your HTML and then restyle it or you can use a little jQuery. The jQuery solution isn't the most clean solution but if you're adamant to use your current HTML structure then it'll work. The jQuery function which I've used changes the `overflow` property of `<ul class="fav-list">` to `visible` once the `<li>` is clicked thus making the `dropdown` menu visible but you won't be able to scroll up and down to view the rest of the `<li>`'s whilst the `dropdown` menu is open. Next, once you click on any other element apart from the `<li>`'s, the `overflow-y` property of `<ul class="fav-list">` is changed to `scroll` so that you can scroll up and down to view the rest of the `<li>`'s.

Here's a demo (view as full page):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( ".dropdown" ).click(function() {
    $(".fav-list").css("overflow","visible");
});

$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $(".dropdown");

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        $(".fav-list").css("overflow-y","scroll");
    }
});
});
```

```css
.fav-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  border-left: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

.fav-bar .fav-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll
}

.fav-bar .fav-list .fav {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.fav-bar .fav-list .fav img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.fav-bar .fav-list .fav .fav-card {
  width: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 65px; /* This would normally be 71px */
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<aside class="fav-bar">
  <h4 class=sr-only>Favorites</h4>
  <ul class="fav-list">
  
    <li class="fav dropdown">
      <a class="fav-thumb dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
         <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/70/70" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="fav-card dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        Some content here
      </div>
    </li>
        
        <li class="fav dropdown">
      <a class="fav-thumb dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
         <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/70/70" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="fav-card dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        Some content here
      </div>
    </li>
            
            <li class="fav dropdown">
      <a class="fav-thumb dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
         <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/70/70" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="fav-card dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        Some content here
      </div>
    </li>
                
                <li class="fav dropdown">
      <a class="fav-thumb dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
         <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/70/70" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="fav-card dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        Some content here
      </div>
    </li>
        
        <li class="fav dropdown">
      <a class="fav-thumb dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
         <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/70/70" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="fav-card dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        Some content here
      </div>
    </li>
        
            <li class="fav dropdown">
      <a class="fav-thumb dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/70/70" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="fav-card dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        Some content here
      </div>
    </li>
                
                    <li class="fav dropdown">
      <a class="fav-thumb dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/70/70" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="fav-card dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        Some content here
      </div>
    </li>
  
    <li class="fav dropdown">
      <a class="fav-thumb dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/70/70" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="fav-card dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        Some content here
      </div>
    </li>
        
            <li class="fav dropdown">
      <a class="fav-thumb dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/70/70" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="fav-card dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        Some content here
      </div>
    </li>
  
    <li class="fav dropdown">
      <a class="fav-thumb dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/70/70" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="fav-card dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        Some content here
      </div>
    </li>
  
    <li class="fav dropdown">
      <a class="fav-thumb dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/70/70" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="fav-card dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        Some content here
      </div>
    </li>
  
    <li class="fav dropdown">
      <a class="fav-thumb dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/70/70" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="fav-card dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        Some content here
      </div>
    </li>
  
    <li class="fav dropdown">
      <a class="fav-thumb dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/70/70" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="fav-card dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        Some content here
      </div>
    </li>
  
  </ul>
</aside>
```

Another solution:

```css
.fav-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  border-left: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
.fav-bar .fav-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  /*** This is what I need ***/
}
.fav-bar .fav-list .fav {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.fav-bar .fav-list .fav img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.fav-bar .fav-list .fav .fav-card {
  width: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 65px;
  /* This would normally be 71px */
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.fav-bar .fav-list .fav .fav-card {
  width: 350px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.open>.dropdown-menu {
  display: inline-block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<aside class="fav-bar">
  <h4 class=sr-only>Favorites</h4>
  <ul class="fav-list">

    <li class="fav dropdown">
      <a class="fav-thumb dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/70/70" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="fav-card dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        Some content here
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="fav dropdown">
      <a class="fav-thumb dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/70/70" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="fav-card dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        Some content here
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="fav dropdown">
      <a class="fav-thumb dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/70/70" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="fav-card dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        Some content here
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="fav dropdown">
      <a class="fav-thumb dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/70/70" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="fav-card dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        Some content here
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="fav dropdown">
      <a class="fav-thumb dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/70/70" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="fav-card dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        Some content here
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="fav dropdown">
      <a class="fav-thumb dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/70/70" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="fav-card dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        Some content here
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="fav dropdown">
      <a class="fav-thumb dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/70/70" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="fav-card dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        Some content here
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="fav dropdown">
      <a class="fav-thumb dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/70/70" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="fav-card dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        Some content here
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="fav dropdown">
      <a class="fav-thumb dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/70/70" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="fav-card dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        Some content here
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="fav dropdown">
      <a class="fav-thumb dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/70/70" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="fav-card dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        Some content here
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="fav dropdown">
      <a class="fav-thumb dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/70/70" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="fav-card dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        Some content here
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="fav dropdown">
      <a class="fav-thumb dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/70/70" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="fav-card dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        Some content here
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="fav dropdown">
      <a class="fav-thumb dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/70/70" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="fav-card dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        Some content here
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="fav dropdown">
      <a class="fav-thumb dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/70/70" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="fav-card dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        Some content here
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="fav dropdown">
      <a class="fav-thumb dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/70/70" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="fav-card dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        Some content here
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="fav dropdown">
      <a class="fav-thumb dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/70/70" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="fav-card dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        Some content here
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="fav dropdown">
      <a class="fav-thumb dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/70/70" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="fav-card dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        Some content here
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="fav dropdown">
      <a class="fav-thumb dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/70/70" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="fav-card dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        Some content here
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="fav dropdown">
      <a class="fav-thumb dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/70/70" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="fav-card dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        Some content here
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="fav dropdown">
      <a class="fav-thumb dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/70/70" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="fav-card dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        Some content here
      </div>
    </li>

  </ul>
</aside>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna try the jQuery solution in the real project (though I will have to ask if the downside of not being able to scroll while a dropdown is open meets the requirements). However, would you mind to elaborate a bit on the other solution? I could go with a bit of markup restructuration (wrapper containers etc.) if that gives a better and more mantainable solution. I just wanted to point that if "big" changes (like replacing the dropdowns with popovers or custom elements) could be avoided, I would prefer to avoid them.

Comment: @seiseises Please check my updated answer above, I've added another solution. It's quite different than what you were trying to achieve in the first place but you might want to consider it since you can't use `overflow-y: scroll` with `overflow-x: visible`. Your HTML remains the same and I've only made a few changes to your CSS.

Comment: Thank you, nice solution, but I'm afraid the interaction differs too much from what was designed: basically a vertical list with googleplus-like or facebook-like popup cards (which I can't replicate because they have crazy and obfuscated markup). Also, I tested your jQuery solution a bit more and found that if I scroll a bit and click an element, the dropdown's vertical offset is calculated based on its `<li>`'s initial position. So if I click an initially-hidden element, the dropdown is generated outside of the viewport. Any idea on how to fix that?